# Google Apps Script: DriveApp.getFileByNames

Tags: google-apps-script

Let me preface this by stating I'm fairly new to programming. Please be gentle :)

I'm creating a GAS that will look up the value in a row 2 column 8, find the file with the filename of the value, and write the fileURL to the row in column 9. Iterate for each row in the sheet.

The script executes, but when I print the variable "value", I get a strange result: "FileIterator". That name just repeats over and over until the last row in the sheet.

See code below:

```
function gdriveFileLink() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DEA Keynote");
   var row = 2; 
   var col = 8;
   var value = ss.getRange(row, col).getValue();
   var writeCell = ss.getRange(row, 9)
   var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
   Logger.log(value);

   while (row <= lastRow) {
     var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(value); **// Here is where I'm having trouble**
     Logger.log(file)
     var url = file.getUrl;          **// No URL gets entered into this variable**
     Logger.log(url);
     var writeCell = ss.getRange(row,9);
     writeCell.setValue(url);
     var row = row + 1;

      }
     }
```

Here is a sample of the execution log:

```
    11:43:26 AM Notice  Execution started
    11:43:26 AM Info    Cascade18
    11:43:26 AM Info    FileIterator
    11:43:26 AM Info    null
    11:43:26 AM Info    FileIterator
    11:43:26 AM Info    null
    11:43:26 AM Info    FileIterator
    Iteration continues to last row in sheet
```

Thanks for your help!

Here is a link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1spALvhKCvjs1M-0JhEWySGA_uu3Gf2pD0ccTUxOeWwg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After mucking around for a few days, I figured out the solution. It was something simple, I needed to add ".next" to this line of code. Then the script worked out great.

var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(value).next;

Answer (score 0):

Get File Links:

```
function gdriveFileLinks() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("DEA Keynote");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();//not sure where data starts
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let files = folder.getFilesByName(r[7]);
    let urls = [];
    while(files.hasNext()) {
      let file = files.next();
      urls.push(file.getUrl())
    }
    sh.getRange(i + 2,9).setValue(urls.join('\n'))
  });
}
```

Comment: Ah I see your edit now, but it's still not functioning as expected. The code completes, but there are no values in the spreadsheet cells.

When I do a logger.log(files) it still showing the value of "FileIterator", looped over and over until it's finished.

Comment: Try it again I was getting the names from the wrong column

Comment: I appreciate your help but that didn't work either. The names are in column 8, the line "let files = folder.getFilesByName(r[8) always returns the value "FileIterator"


From what I can tell FileIterator is a class that allows scripts to iterate over large collection of files.


https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator

What's more interesting is if I replace r[7] with one of the file names "Cascade18" i still get a return value of "FileIterator"

Comment: Is there only one name in each cell of column 8

Comment: I just tested it on one of my sheets with names in column 8 and I got urls in column 9

Comment: Yes, only one name in each cell of column 8. I copied your code again to make sure nothing funky happened. I added two lines, Logger.log(files) and Logger.log(urls). Here is the return for each of those: 2:59:21 PM Info FileIterator
2:59:21 PM Info []

I double checked the folder id, its good. I will try to attach my sheet to this post.

Comment: Do those names of files have extensions?

Comment: They are .jpg. I tried adding the file extension. Still the same issue with "FileIterator"

Comment: That didn't work :(

Comment: I don't have an answer.  I just tried with a folder that has images and it works for me

Comment: Thanks for your help Cooper. You put me on the right path.